# Can a Fivetran destination table be used for writing after canceling synchronisation on this table?

Tags: fivetran

I have multiple Fivetran destination tables in the Snowflake. Those tables were created by the Fivetran itself and the Fivetran currently writes data into the tables. Now I would like to stop syncing data in one of the tables and start writing to the table from a different source. Would I experience any troubles with this? Should I do something else in to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you mention is not possible because of how Fivetran works. Connector sources write to one destination schema and one only. Swapping destination tables between connectors is not a feature as of now.